# Regular expression to find and replace full matches (consecutive repeats, preserve delimiter)

Tags: regex, notepad++

It's necessary that when searching, complete matches of words/phrases are found and replaced with new ones:

- If the value is blank, then delete.
- If the value is not blank, then replace it with a word/phrase while maintaining the separator.

### Original Text:

```
1:
Coconut
2:
ACoconut
3:
Coconut!
4:
!CoconutA

5:
Coconut,Orange,Coconut,Pear,Coconut
6:
ACoconut,Orange,Coconut!,Pear,!CoconutA

7:
Coconut,Coconut
8:
ACoconut,Coconut!
9:
Coconut,Coconut,Coconut
10:
ACoconut,Coconut!,!CoconutA

11:
Coconut,Coconut,Orange
12:
ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
13:
Coconut,Coconut,Coconut,Orange
14:
Coconut,ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
15:
Orange,Coconut,Coconut,Pear
16:
Orange,Coconut,CoconutA,Pear

17:
Orange,Coconut,Coconut,Coconut,Pear
18:
Orange,ACoconut,Coconut,!Coconut,Pear
19:
Pear,Coconut,Coconut
20:
Pear,Coconut!,Coconut
21:
Pear,!Coconut,Coconut,ACoconut
22:
Pear,CoconutA,!Coconut,Coconut
```

### Expected Results:

**Nuances:**

1. I use Notepad++ for search and replace.
2. If there are extra characters before and/or after a word/phrase, this is not a complete match (only commas are ignored).
3. If a word/phrase is repeated sequentially through a delimiter (in this case, a comma), then this sequence is replaced by one word/phrase. It doesn’t matter whether this sequence starts from the very beginning, in the middle or from the end of the text.
4. There must be a complete match of the word/phrase (for this, my expression uses ^, comma delimiter and $). I don't have to specify the separator myself when replacing text, this should be done using part of the expression (capturing groups).

- ### Replace with:   - means blank, not space

  ```
  1:

  2:
  ACoconut
  3:
  Coconut!
  4:
  !CoconutA

  5:
  Orange,Pear
  6:
  ACoconut,Orange,Coconut!,Pear,!CoconutA

  7:

  8:
  ACoconut,Coconut!
  9:

  10:
  ACoconut,Coconut!,!CoconutA

  11:
  Orange
  12:
  ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
  13:
  Orange
  14:
  ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
  15:
  Orange,Pear
  16:
  Orange,CoconutA,Pear

  17:
  Orange,Pear
  18:
  Orange,ACoconut,!Coconut,Pear
  19:
  Pear
  20:
  Pear,Coconut!
  21:
  Pear,!Coconut,ACoconut
  22:
  Pear,CoconutA,!Coconut
  ```
- ### Replace with: `Tomato`

  ```
  1:
  Tomato
  2:
  ACoconut
  3:
  Coconut!
  4:
  !CoconutA

  5:
  Tomato,Orange,Tomato,Pear,Tomato
  6:
  ACoconut,Orange,Coconut!,Pear,!CoconutA

  7:
  Tomato
  8:
  ACoconut,Coconut!
  9:
  Tomato
  10:
  ACoconut,Coconut!,!CoconutA

  11:
  Tomato,Orange
  12:
  ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
  13:
  Tomato,Orange
  14:
  Tomato,ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
  15:
  Orange,Tomato,Pear
  16:
  Orange,Tomato,CoconutA,Pear

  17:
  Orange,Tomato,Pear
  18:
  Orange,ACoconut,Tomato,!Coconut,Pear
  19:
  Pear,Tomato
  20:
  Pear,Coconut!,Tomato
  21:
  Pear,!Coconut,Tomato,ACoconut
  22:
  Pear,CoconutA,!Coconut,Tomato
  ```

### My Try (with Results):

- **Find what:** `^(Coconut)$|^(Coconut)(,)|(,)(Coconut)(,)|(,)(Coconut)$`

  1. **Replace with:** `$4$7$3$6`

     ```
     1:

     2:
     ACoconut
     3:
     Coconut!
     4:
     !CoconutA

     5:
     ,Orange,,Pear,
     6:
     ACoconut,Orange,Coconut!,Pear,!CoconutA

     7:
     ,Coconut
     8:
     ACoconut,Coconut!
     9:
     ,Coconut,
     10:
     ACoconut,Coconut!,!CoconutA

     11:
     ,Coconut,Orange
     12:
     ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
     13:
     ,Coconut,,Orange
     14:
     ,ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
     15:
     Orange,,Coconut,Pear
     16:
     Orange,,CoconutA,Pear

     17:
     Orange,,Coconut,,Pear
     18:
     Orange,ACoconut,,!Coconut,Pear
     19:
     Pear,,Coconut
     20:
     Pear,Coconut!,
     21:
     Pear,!Coconut,,ACoconut
     22:
     Pear,CoconutA,!Coconut,
     ```
  2. **Replace with:** `$4$7Tomato$3$6`

     ```
     1:
     Tomato
     2:
     ACoconut
     3:
     Coconut!
     4:
     !CoconutA

     5:
     Tomato,Orange,Tomato,Pear,Tomato
     6:
     ACoconut,Orange,Coconut!,Pear,!CoconutA

     7:
     Tomato,Coconut
     8:
     ACoconut,Coconut!
     9:
     Tomato,Coconut,Tomato
     10:
     ACoconut,Coconut!,!CoconutA

     11:
     Tomato,Coconut,Orange
     12:
     ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
     13:
     Tomato,Coconut,Tomato,Orange
     14:
     Tomato,ACoconut,!Coconut,Orange
     15:
     Orange,Tomato,Coconut,Pear
     16:
     Orange,Tomato,CoconutA,Pear

     17:
     Orange,Tomato,Coconut,Tomato,Pear
     18:
     Orange,ACoconut,Tomato,!Coconut,Pear
     19:
     Pear,Tomato,Coconut
     20:
     Pear,Coconut!,Tomato
     21:
     Pear,!Coconut,Tomato,ACoconut
     22:
     Pear,CoconutA,!Coconut,Tomato
     ```

Comment: `Coconut,?|,?Coconut`

Comment: @CAustin No, not universal at all.

Comment: @Grobu Not really. It ignores extra characters (including special ones) before the word, and this is already an incomplete match. When replacing, I will have to set the separator myself (i.e. a comma), but it should be through part of the regular expression (capturing groups).

Comment: Extra characters? Which ones? What language are using to perform replacement? Please update your poste with more detailed requirements.

Comment: @Grobu Any symbols in principle. There must be a complete match of the word/phrase (for this, my expression uses ^, comma delimiter and $). I don't have to specify the separator myself when replacing text, this should be done using part of the expression.

Comment: @Grobu I do the replacement via Notepad++.

Comment: Please update your post by further detailing your requirements and providing a relevant input sample for us to be able to understand and help you.

Comment: Updated the list and added more details.

Comment: @Grobu Doesn't work correctly with number 22 from the list. I also need a replacement expression, since two cases are considered.

Comment: @Grobu What about REGEXREPLACE in Google Sheets?

Comment: there is some info on [mre], and this question writer did not read that.... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Coconut(?:,|$)|(?:^|,)Coconut(?:,Coconut)*$|(,)Coconut(?:,Coconut)*(?:,|$)`
- Replace with: `(?1$1)`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  ^               # beginning of line
    Coconut         # literally
    (?:,|$)         # a comma or end of line
|               # OR
    (?:^|,)         # beginning of line or comma
    Coconut         # literally
    (?:,Coconut)*   # a comma followed by Coconut, may appear 0 or more times
  $               # end of line
|               # OR
    (,)             # group 1, a comma
    Coconut         # literally
    (?:,Coconut)*   # a comma followed by Coconut, may appear 0 or more times
    (?:,|$)         # comma or end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1$1)          # if group 1 exists, print it
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

---

Replace with `Tomato`:

- Find what: `(^|,)Coconut(?:,Coconut)*(,|$)`
- Replace with: `$1Tomato$2`

Comment: **In the second case** it works great. **In the first case:** 1) when replacing with `(?1$1)`, it leaves a comma at the end (number 19 from the list); 2) when replacing `leave empty`, it skips commas = words are merged (numbers 5, 15-18, 21 from the list).

Comment: Great. I think `leave empty` is useless. Works correctly with `(?1$1)`. You are a god.

Comment: Just now I discovered that **in the first case** the expression does not see the sequence (for example: `Coconut,Coconut`) and deletes only the first `Coconut,`.

Comment: @StesMus: What line doesn't work? I just see `Coconut,Coconut` in line 7 and the result is an empty line.

Comment: I understand why. This is due to the unchecked `Wrap around`. I was trying to use an expression via REGEXREPLACE in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, **without capturing groups**.

No particular added value compared to the other answer. Just wanted to challenge myself.

#### Delete expressions

`^Coconut(?:,Coconut)*(?:,|$)|(?:,Coconut)+(?=,|$)`

Result:

```
Coconut                               ... 
Coconut,Orange,Coconut,Pear,Coconut   ... Orange,Pear
Coconut,Coconut                       ... 
Coconut,Coconut,Coconut               ... 
Coconut,Coconut,Orange                ... Orange
Coconut,Coconut,Coconut,Orange        ... Orange
Orange,Coconut,Coconut,Pear           ... Orange,Pear
Orange,Coconut,Coconut,Coconut,Pear   ... Orange,Pear
Pear,Coconut,Coconut                  ... Pear
Pear,Coconut,Coconut,Coconut          ... Pear
CCoconut                              ... CCoconut
Coconut,Orange,CCoconut,Pear,Coconutt ... Orange,CCoconut,Pear,Coconutt
Coconut,CCoconut                      ... CCoconut
Coconutt,another Coconutt,Coconut     ... Coconutt,another Coconutt
Coconut,My Coconut,Orange             ... My Coconut,Orange
Coconut,Coconut,Your Coconut,Orange   ... Your Coconut,Orange
Orange,Coconutt,Coconut,Pear          ... Orange,Coconutt,Pear
Orange,Coconut,a Coconut,Coconut,Pear ... Orange,a Coconut,Pear
Pear,CCoconut,Coconut                 ... Pear,CCoconut
Pear,Coconut,CCoconut,Coconut         ... Pear,CCoconut
```

#### Replace expressions

`^Coconut(?:,Coconut)*(?=,|$)|(?<=,)Coconut(?:,Coconut)*(?=,|$)`

Result:

```
Coconut                               ... BANANA
Coconut,Orange,Coconut,Pear,Coconut   ... BANANA,Orange,BANANA,Pear,BANANA
Coconut,Coconut                       ... BANANA
Coconut,Coconut,Coconut               ... BANANA
Coconut,Coconut,Orange                ... BANANA,Orange
Coconut,Coconut,Coconut,Orange        ... BANANA,Orange
Orange,Coconut,Coconut,Pear           ... Orange,BANANA,Pear
Orange,Coconut,Coconut,Coconut,Pear   ... Orange,BANANA,Pear
Pear,Coconut,Coconut                  ... Pear,BANANA
Pear,Coconut,Coconut,Coconut          ... Pear,BANANA
CCoconut                              ... CCoconut
Coconut,Orange,CCoconut,Pear,Coconutt ... BANANA,Orange,CCoconut,Pear,Coconutt
Coconut,CCoconut                      ... BANANA,CCoconut
Coconutt,another Coconutt,Coconut     ... Coconutt,another Coconutt,BANANA
Coconut,My Coconut,Orange             ... BANANA,My Coconut,Orange
Coconut,Coconut,Your Coconut,Orange   ... BANANA,Your Coconut,Orange
Orange,Coconutt,Coconut,Pear          ... Orange,Coconutt,BANANA,Pear
Orange,Coconut,a Coconut,Coconut,Pear ... Orange,BANANA,a Coconut,BANANA,Pear
Pear,CCoconut,Coconut                 ... Pear,CCoconut,BANANA
Pear,Coconut,CCoconut,Coconut         ... Pear,BANANA,CCoconut,BANANA
```

Tested with Notepad++ in Wine on Debian 11.